# When I am trying to deploy a simple contract with 0 ether or even 2 ether in remix It is giving the following error

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Error:

> creation of FundMe errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert
> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

Here is the code for FundMe.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract FundMe {

    function fund() payable public{
        require(msg.value > 1e18, "don't have enough ETH");
    } 

}
```

I tried with the different browser tabs, also tried with sending enough ether for deployment but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your contract needs to declare a `payable` `constructor` in order to accept ETH while deploying.

```
contract FundMe {
    constructor() payable {
        // can be empty and without arguments
    }

    // TODO rest of your code
}
```

It's the same with every function. Your `fund()` is payable, so that it can already accept ETH.